# window.navigate and document.location issue

Tags: c#, javascript

I am working on a system that after completing a record edit and returning control to the calling AJAX script, I refresh the calling page by calling a custom server extension.  The odd behavior I am experiencing is after control is returned to the calling script, when the code hits window.navigate or document.location, it attempts to navigate to the url in a new window (which is not the desired behavior).  Additionally, the custom server extension is never called - the url appears in the address bar, but then does nothing.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  I am running IIS 5.1 on XP sp3 and have tried to get it to work in IE 8 and IE 7, to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my tech lead is apparently a much better Googler than I am.

http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/13307/fid/53

Long story short: the page I am calling from is modal and only has an HTML rendering dll loaded.  So we changed the return value of the modal page we called from a scalar value to an object with data and now I get to go repopulate the fields manually in the modal calling page.